# JXLS: How to add If-command condition for date column in XML markup

Tags: jxls

I am using XML markup to use JXLS library. I I have defined the XML file but I am not sure how to add condition for date; I want to compare if the `endDate` column value is <= today's date.

I tried the below code but is is not working:

```
<area ref="Template!A9:F9">
    <if condition="DATEVALUE(countryGrid.endDate) &gt;= TODATE()" ref="Template!A9:F9">
        <area ref="Template!A18:F18"/>
        <area ref="Template!A9:F9"/>
    </if>
</area>
```

Comment: I have tried below but it's not working
<if condition="DATEVALUE(countryGrid.endDate) &gt;= TODATE()" ref="Template!A9:K10">
      <area ref="Template!A9:K9"/>
      <area ref="Template!A10:K10"/>
     </if>

Comment: It would be easyer to read your message if you add you code to your question inline by editing your question. Allso please show the result of what you did in your code. Did you get any errors? BR